# ¿Por qué la lectura del id en la base de datos es incorrecta (o no se actualiza) cuando hago una consulta?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, flask

Contexto: Estoy trabajando una app web con flask y quiero registrar lotes con un id único, este id lo estoy generando automáticamente sin necesidad de que alguien lo escriba, para eso hice lo siguiente

```
@app.route('/registrar_lote', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def registrar_lote():
   if request.method == 'POST':
    id_lote=request.form['id_lote']
    fecha=datetime.now()
    peso=request.form['peso']
    inspeccion=request.form['inspeccion']
    with mysql.cursor() as cur:
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO lotes VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                    (id_lote, fecha, peso, inspeccion))
            cur.connection.commit()
            flash("El lote se ha registrado correctamente", "success")
        except:
            flash("Ha ocurrido un error al registrar el lote", "error")

        return redirect(url_for('registrar_lote'))

else:
    cur = mysql.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM lotes ORDER BY id_lote DESC LIMIT 1")
    lote_cursor = cur.fetchone()
    # Generando el id automaticamente
    if lote_cursor is None:
        lote_cursor=0 
    else:    
        lote_cursor=lote_cursor[0]
    print(lote_cursor)    
    
    loteareg=lote_cursor+1
    
return render_template('registrolote.html', loteareg=loteareg)
```

Los formularios están recibiendo toda la información y se guarda correctamente en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo HTML tengo esto ( Invisibilizo la entrada para el registrador pero igual pongo un texto para que sepa cuál es el que se va a registrar y no lo tenga que incluir; también, omito las demás entradas para que no sea tan largo)

```html
 <div class="card-body">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style2.css') }}">
    <form action="/registrar_lote" method="POST" class="px-5">

      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Lote n.° {{loteareg}}</h1>
        <input class="invisible" type="number" name="code" value="{{loteareg}}" class="form-control" id="codeInput",>
 <div class="row-cols-lg-3 flex-center ">

 <button type="submit" class="btn mdb-color text-white">Registrar
     lote</button>
         </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Al insertar los datos se registra el id autogenerado con el script y me retorna de nuevo a la página con el texto listo con el id siguiente ─o sea el 2─ y al volver a llenar el formulario se registrará con el 2 y así sucesivamente. El problema como puse en el titulo es que por ejemplo en la imagen anexada de la vista de la base de datos, al eliminar ese registro, me gustaría que al refrescar la página, me mostrara que el id que se va a registrar va a ser el 1 otra vez ya que borré el registro, pero no, me sigue mostrando el número 2 y solo se actualiza correctamente si detengo y vuelvo a correr la aplicación (el archivo .py)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te recomiendo leer un poco sobre como generar un ID unico, quiza te pueda servir: https://laingenieria.info/questions/2096/usando-un-guid-como-clave-principal

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Las bases de datos no manejan los autonumericos asi... Son ID, identificadores internos y cuando borras uno no van a cubrir los baches, usan un secuencial donde no le importan los baches. Si el id es importante para vos, deberas manejarlo de otra manera. Asi que si, tu base de datos lo esta haciendo bien.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta. Por cierto, me queda la duda, ignorando que sea un id o no, ¿por qué solo funciona cuando detengo y vuelvo a ejecutar el script (el .py)?